# jquery when fires before I'm finished with my success handler

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I'm not sure if I'm reading the documentation correctly, but I thought that $.when in jquery would allow me to do multiple asynch calls and then in the `done` portion of the function, I'd be able to call another function.  I basically am trying to fetch all of my data before rendering my view.  Some of the items are in backbone objects, some I have to manually call with an ajax call since there's no backbone object that corresponds to the info.

```
var fetchLibraries = function () {
      if (this.screen == "EDIT") {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'libraries',
                        type: "GET",
                        crossDomain: $.support.cors,
                        xhrFields: {
                            withCredentials: $.support.cors
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            // do some processing with the data that can take some time
                        }
                    });
                }
               }
            };

            $.when(this.platforms.fetch(),
                fetchLibraries()).done(function () {
                self.trigger('removeOverlay');
                self.render();
            });
```

So normally, this works as I expect and my render function gets called after the fetchLibraries success callback.  Sometimes, usually when my server is waking up and the calls take awhile, the self.render() gets called before I'm finished processing the fetchLibraries.  I have a console.log in both the self.render function and the success callback, when it doesn't work, I basically see "render" logged before I see the "data" logged.  I was wondering if there was a way to make sure that the fetchLibraries finishes it's success callback before calling render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods passed to `when` should return a promise.

```
var fetchLibraries = function () {
  if (this.screen == "EDIT") {
    return $.ajax({ //return the promise
        url: 'libraries',
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: $.support.cors,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: $.support.cors
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            // do some processing with the data that can take some time
        }
    });
  }
};

$.when(this.platforms.fetch(), fetchLibraries()).done(function () {
    self.trigger('removeOverlay');
    self.render();
});
```

Comment: This is related to JQuery's deferreds: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 0):

what will happen if you write like that:

```
var fetchLibraries = function () {
   if (this.screen == "EDIT") {
       $.ajax({
         url: 'libraries',
         type: "GET",
         crossDomain: $.support.cors,
         xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: $.support.cors
         }
      });
   }
  };

 $.when(this.platforms.fetch(), fetchLibraries()).done(function (data) {
      // write success's body here 
      self.trigger('removeOverlay');
      self.render();
 });
```